# Force JSON.stringify to escape forward slash (i.e. `\/`)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm writing a service in `nodejs` that replaces an existing system written in `.NET`. The service provides a JSON API, one of the calls returns a date. The Microsoft date format for JSON was/is where `1599890827000` is the milliseconds offset:

`/Date(1599890827000)/`

The problem I am having is that `JSON.stringify` (used in `res.send` and `res.json` in `express`) does not escape forward slashes but the existing Microsoft library ([System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx))  expects forward slashes to be escaped.

For example, the client expects JSON like this:

```
{
  "Expires": "\/Date(1599890827000)\/"
}
```

But `JSON.stringify` produces the following:

```
{
  "Expires": "/Date(1599890827000)/"
}
```

The second result is perfectly valid but the Microsoft library doesn't like it and fails to parse.

**Is there any way I can force Express/Node/JSON to escape forward slashes in `JSON.stringify` or handle this case?**

I could use a regex replacement after running `stringify` but because of an object caching system we use in the project it would be very hacky to have to convert to JSON before sending to the client instead of letting.

Note: I cannot change the client, only the api service.

Comment: *"but the existing Microsoft library (System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer) expects forward slashes to be escaped"* Not in my experience. That would be seriously weird, as there's exactly no reason to escape them either in JSON or in JavaScript. I suspect your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Strange indeed but without the escaped forward slash I get this exception `System.FormatException: /Date(1599898027000)/ is not a valid value for DateTime.` and I cannot change the client

Comment: Better late than never, but I've got an explanation for the behavior.  [This blog post from 2008](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/dates-and-json) outlines the .NET team's decision here; basically, they needed a way to differentiate dates from strings, and decided to intentionally use escaped forward slashes for that purpose since "there actually is no reason that I can think of why you'd want to do that".  Personal opinion: definitely not the best decision to come out of Redmond.  But it's one that's made it into the wild regardless.

Answer (score 6):

[Replacer happens before escaping](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3), leaving you with either:

```
"/Date(1599890827000)/"
```

Or:

```
"\\/Date(1599890827000)\\/"
```

Realistically you will have to run a string replace on the resulting output:

```
JSON.stringify(data).replace(/\//g, '\\/');
```

This means that you won't be able to use the express built in [`res.json(data)`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/b5a280111f94728e70aa1a22687e64aaf31abd81/lib/response.js#L222) and may need to instead write a function to replace it like:

```
function dotNetJSONResponse(res, data) {

    var app = res.app;
    var replacer = app.get('json replacer');
    var spaces = app.get('json spaces');
    var body = JSON.stringify(data, replacer, spaces);

    if (!this.get('Content-Type')) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }

    return res.send(body.replace(/\//g, '\\/'));
}
```

Calling it as:

```
app.get('/url', function (req, res) {
     dotNetJSONResponse(res, data);
});
```

*However*, that said, fixing the behaviour in .NET would be the more forward compatible solution.

Comment: yeah this is what I'm thinking :(

Answer (score 3):

Use [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) parameter

```
function replaceSlashes(key, value) 
{
  if ( typeof value == "string")
  {
    value = value.replace(/\//g, "\\/");
  }
  return value;
}

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonString, replaceSlashes);
```

It will still produce a double backward slash since stringify method by itself won't product a single slash without escaping the same.\

You need to try something like this

```
JSON.stringify({
  "Expires": "\/Date(1599890827000)\/"
}, replaceSlashes).replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please check now, it is escaping now

Comment: Thanks but this produces `\\/Date(1599890827000)\\/` instead of `\/Date(1599890827000)\/`I guess because stringify is then escaping the new backslash

Comment: @antfx It won't be possible directly with stringify method. You will need to try something like `JSON.stringify({
  "Expires": "\/Date(1599890827000)\/"
}, replaceSlashes).replace(/\\\\/g, "\\")` Check the updates

Comment: Yeah it works but as I mentioned in my original post, I ideally wanted something to set either globally or in Express because of an object caching system we use

Comment: @antfx I am not sure if I have understood `either globally or in Express` . Sorry, I have not worked on Express.js, if that is what you meant.

Comment: Beware that this code may have unexpected results with other items in the JSON object: https://jsfiddle.net/5c48vr6r/