# Exactly reproduce PHP's json_encode result in JavaScript/NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js

In JavaScript (NodeJS), I'm trying to validate a payload's origin with HMAC signature made using PHP process of:

```
$raw_json = '{"link":"https://data.com.sg/resource?2f6b5c55-c8cb-4398-875c-a1c69e0d2706"}';  
$payload = json_decode($raw_json, true);  
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', json_encode($payload), 'SECRET_KEY');
```

using similar JS process of:

```
const rawJSON = '{"link":"https://data.com.sg/resource?2f6b5c55-c8cb-4398-875c-a1c69e0d2706"}';
const payload = JSON.parse(rawJSON)
const signature = HMACSHA256(JSON.stringify(payload), 'SECRET_KEY');
```

But I found that the length of `JSON.stringify(payload)` and `json_encode($payload)` is different. Logging both data, I found that that is an issue in escaped character resulted when doing json_encode on string with link or `/` character (or maybe any other).

> *JavaScript's JSON.stringify results*
>
> `{"link":"https://data.com.sg/resource?2f6b5c55-c8cb-4398-875c-a1c69e0d2706"}`
>
> *PHP's json_encode results*
>
> `{"link":"https:\/\/data.com.sg\/resource?2f6b5c55-c8cb-4398-875c-a1c69e0d2706"}`

I cannot change the process in PHP system side. So I gotta adapt the HMAC generation process in the nodejs system side.

**What can be done so I could reproduce `json_encode` in JavaScript flawlessly?**

*Pls see P.S.*

---

P.S.

*I've tried using some [json_encode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json_encode) module but it's still giving me the same result as `JSON.stringify`.*

*For now I'm tackling it by adding replacer [talked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841447/force-json-stringify-to-escape-forward-slash-i-e). But as my payload will be full of formatted text, **I'm concerned with the possibility of another case of result differences due to characters existence other than `/` char. Or should I be not concerned about that?***

Comment: You might find this interesting ~ [json_encode() escaping forward slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10210338/283366). In my opinion, PHP is a little over-zealous with its defaults.

Comment: no, I don't have access to edit the signature generation process in PHP system @Phil

Comment: Damn, that's unfortunate. I think you're stuck with the replacer then. Consult the PHP documentation to see what else `json_encode()` does by default

Comment: In PHP you can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag and it won't add forward slashes